# Microsoft Graph API token expiring after 3600 seconds - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to generate oAuth 2.0 access token, which expires after  1 Hour. Route being used is: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BTenant) ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token
I am passing these values in the Query string.
{
grant_type: "client_credentials",
client_id: `APP_ID`,
client_secret: `APP_PASSWORD`,
scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
}

Now, my current implementation I have added recursion in which I added retries before calling a graph api to extract user details from AD.

Is there a way I can get/fetch a refresh token, because refresh tokens last longer?

Answer (score 1):

In my view, use of refresh token along with client crendential flow is of no use. Why would you want to have an additional step added to get access token when you can get that straight away.

Flow with the **client_credentials** grant type:

Step 1: client authentication

OK access token is issued

Flow for obtaining **Refresh_token**

Step 1: client authentication

Step 2: Refresh token validation and use it to obtain access token

OK access token is issued.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps to enable Refresh Tokens:

1. Request the scope **'offline_access'**. This will tell the endpoint to provide a refresh_token along with the access_token and associated metadata.
2. You need to request a new access_token (and refresh_token as they come together) by repeating the same POST to /common/oauth2/v2.0/token with a slightly different body - grant_type is set to **refresh_token** and instead of a code, you supply a refresh_token property and value

For e.g.

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=[client Id]
&scope=[scope]
&refresh_token=[refresh token]
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_secret=[secret]
```

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth-get-tokens?view=bingads-13) for refresh token request details.

Comment: I am not using the authorize endpoint, hence not getting the redirect uri and code that is passed to the /common/oauth2/v2.0/token api. I am using the grant type as client credentials and If I replace it to 'offline_access' as you said. I get this in the response:  The app requested an unsupported grant type \'offline_access\'